# maven plugins that will not be supported in maven 4

Tags: maven

I'm trying to prepare many projects for maven 4 for whenever it comes out. Is there a known list of plugins that will not work? Or should all the core plugins at least start with a 3.x for their version?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't think there is already a source for this. You can try, though, with 3.9.1 and 4.0.0-alpha5 to get a first impression. Already 3.9.1 has some breaking changes for plugins.

Comment: What breaking changes do you know about? I've got a test of 3.9.1 on a subset of projects but not everything.

Comment: see https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.9.1/release-notes.html#potentially-breaking-core-changes-if-migrating-from-3-8-x

Comment: @JFabianMeier is correct about that.. The most problematic part is that plugins are even using very old api's (partially Maven 2 and some other strange things etc.) and other stuff.. All so called "core" plugins (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/) should work.. at the moment there are some plugins which have some issues which will be fixed... Maven 4  (alpha at the moment) is already available as 4.0.0-alpha-5 (see https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) it would be great if you could test your projects already and see if something breaks would be great to have such feedback...

Comment: In general the project shouldn't needed to be changed only plugins should be upgraded to most recent versions... that should it be... ...

Comment: In the short term, I've made a repo where I'm trying to collect what issues I've found.
https://github.com/sellersj/maven-4-migration-checks

I totally understand it should just be to use the latest plugins, but it's easier if I can say "the version X you're using isn't compatible and you need to use at least version Y".